# Duplicate data when using Snowflake SQL left join

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm having trouble understanding LEFT JOIN results in Snowflake.

```
select * from
(select 1 as AccountIdA) s
LEFT OUTER JOIN (Select 1 as AccountIdB, 'Val1' as Col1 union select 1, 'Val2' as Col1) t1 on t1.AccountIdB = s.AccountIdA
LEFT OUTER JOIN (Select 1 as AccountIdC, 'Val3' as Col2) t2 on t2.AccountIdC = s.AccountIdA
```

The SQL above results in the following:

| AccountIdA | AccountIdB | Col1 | AccountIdC | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | VAL1 | 1 | VAL3 |
| 1 | 1 | VAL2 | 1 | VAL3 |

However, I am expecting the following, because there is only one row match from the second left join.

| AccountIdA | AccountIdB | Col1 | AccountIdC | Col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | VAL1 | 1 | VAL3 |
| 1 | 1 | VAL2 | null | null |

Is there any logic to this?  Any way to get the result that I'm expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so just reformed that SQL so is was less wide, and just to make sense of it.

```
select * from (
    select 1 as AccountIdA
) s
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES (1,'val1'), (1,  'Val2') v(AccountIdB, col1)
) t1 on t1.AccountIdB = s.AccountIdA
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES (1,'val3') v(AccountIdC, col2)
) t2 on t2.AccountIdC = s.AccountIdA;
```

But you get two rows, because of standard SQL logic. The joins happen is serial, thus you first have `s` with a single `AccountIdA` of `1`.

| AccountIdA |
| --- |
| 1 |

Then we join to `t1` and we have

| AccountIdA | AccountIdB | col1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 'val1' |
| 1 | 1 | 'val2' |

no surprises here:

now we join to `t2` on where given we have 2 rows with `AccountIdA` we match the `AccountIdC` against both of those, and given they are both `1` we match both rows.

| AccountIdA | AccountIdB | col1 | AccountIdC | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 'val1' | 1 | 'val3' |
| 1 | 1 | 'val2' | 1 | 'val3' |

now what a LEFT JOIN gives you is if the left side is not matched by the right side we get NULL, this can swapping some things around like:

```
select * from (
    select column1 as AccountIdA FROM VALUES (1),(2),(3)
) s
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES (1,'val1'), (2,  'Val2') v(AccountIdB, col1)
) t1 on t1.AccountIdB = s.AccountIdA
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES (3,'val3') v(AccountIdC, col2)
) t2 on t2.AccountIdC = s.AccountIdA;
```

now we get matches on the keys that make sense, and no matches on the others.

| ACCOUNTIDA | ACCOUNTIDB | COL1 | ACCOUNTIDC | COL2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | val1 |  |  |
| 2 | 2 | Val2 |  |  |
| 3 |  |  | 3 | val3 |

So this goes to show when doing JOINs you have to make sure you have de-duplicated data, otherwise you can get multiplication of the rows

```
select * from (
    select column1 as AccountIdA FROM VALUES (1),(1)
) s
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES (1,'val1'), (1,  'Val2') v(AccountIdB, col1)
) t1 on t1.AccountIdB = s.AccountIdA
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES (1,'val3'),(1,'val4') v(AccountIdC, col2)
) t2 on t2.AccountIdC = s.AccountIdA;
```

gives an explosion to:

| ACCOUNTIDA | ACCOUNTIDB | COL1 | ACCOUNTIDC | COL2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | val1 | 1 | val3 |
| 1 | 1 | val1 | 1 | val4 |
| 1 | 1 | Val2 | 1 | val3 |
| 1 | 1 | Val2 | 1 | val4 |
| 1 | 1 | val1 | 1 | val3 |
| 1 | 1 | val1 | 1 | val4 |
| 1 | 1 | Val2 | 1 | val3 |
| 1 | 1 | Val2 | 1 | val4 |